# RenderPartial method in Razor view

Tags: .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I know that in razor syntax we have to keep the RenderPartial method inside the curly braces. Also, that it returns void and is written directly to the output stream.

eg.-
`@{ Html.RenderPartial("Category","Home"); }`

Now, I have two questions 1. What is an output stream 2. What is the significance of the curly braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly brace syntax just means that some C#/VB code exists there. It informs Razor to parse everything within as straight code.

Now, saying it gets written directly to the output stream is a bit simplistic. Essentially, in building a response for the server to send to the client, the response *body* is a stream. The "output stream" is essentially the same thing as the "response body". When Razor parse a view, it begins writing to that response body, and essentially `Html.RenderPartial` writes directly to the response body, as well, rather than returning something to Razor which Razor would then write to the response body.

That said, just use `Html.Partial` unless you have a good reason otherwise:

```
@Html.Partial("Category", "Home")
```